# Bouncy Castle Getting content from signature and X509Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, public-key, message-digest

I am very new to Bouncy Castle.I want to know is there any way using Bouncy Castle API that i can get original content if i only have signature using X509Certificate with public key.I am not finding any way as we have only public key.We don't have private key which is used to sign the message.

Comment: We have public key as X509Certificate

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: I want to get the content from signature string.

Answer (score 0):

If one has created a *detached* signature and you have only that signature (and no original data) then you are out of luck.

If the signature is wrapping, then surely you can get original data back. Signed data doesn't require a private key to be verified and extracted. Public key (actually the certificate with the key) can be included in the wrapping signature in which case you don't even need the certificate separately.

Comment: Yes correct, actually i have wrapped signature just i want to verify the signature,but i am always getting Message Digest miss match exception so i just want to get the Content from signature,to check original content content which i have for comparison .So any method or code that will retrieve content from signature for my verification will be helpful.